# UI Kitten - RangeCalendar component is not fitting with the mobile screen width. How to handle the width of the component?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

UI Kitten - RangeCalendar component is not fitting with the mobile screen width. I don't see the width property in the document https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/calendar/api#rangecalendar.

How to handle the width of that component?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is taking the parent element width. We need to provide 100% width to the parent element to make the calendar fit to that element.